# Sort a LINQ with another LINQ in MVC

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, controller

- Using SQL Server Management
- Using MVC VS 2013 for Web
- Being in a Controller

Here *materialnumb* it's a LINQ query that **always** return only one value.
Being the following...

```
var materialnumb = (from r in db.MaterialNumber
                                   where r.MaterialNumber == 80254842
                                   select r.MaterialNumber);
```

I have another LINQ query from a SQL view that involves several other tables with inner join statements and so on (which includes the previous table db.MaterialNumber) that goes like this:

```
var query = (from r in db.SQLViewFinalTable
                                where r.MaterialNumber == Convert.ToInt32(materialnumb.MaterialNumber)
                                select r
```

I want to sort all the materials by the retrieved material number from the first query but it drops the following error when I try to pass the query as a model for my View:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

I assume this is because the query is an object even if its has just one value so it can't be converted into a single Int32.
Even more, the query it's not being executed, it's just a query...

So, how can achieve my goal?

Additional information: I tried to convert the query outside the "final" query. It still doesn't work.
Additional information: This is just an example, the true query actually has several more other querys embedded and this other querys have also other querys in them, so I need a practical way. 
Additional information: I have also tried to convert the query into a string and then again into an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var materialnumb = (from r in db.MaterialNumber
                    where r.MaterialNumber == 80254842
                    select r.MaterialNumber).FirstOrDefault();

var query = from r in db.SQLViewFinalTable
            where r.MaterialNumber == materialnumb
            select r
```

But I can not get whay are you filtering by 80254842 and selecting the same value? You can do directly:

```
var query = from r in db.SQLViewFinalTable
            where r.MaterialNumber == 80254842
            select r
```

Comment: I'm putting the number there because in the real query I'm using I would have made _materialnumb_ incorporate another query and so on. Each subsequent query must filter values because thats how the tables were made, I can't change that.
So I wanted something easy to explain.
That worked out. Thanks!